# Qt stylesheet : set a specific QMenuBar::item background color

Tags: qt, qmenubar

I have a `QMenuBar` with for example two `QMenu` items.

[image]

How can I only make the "Floors" item be blue, for example? I know how to change it for ALL the items with:

```
QMenuBar::item {
     background: ...;
}
```

But I can't find a way to color a specific item. I tried to use `setProperty` on `Qmenu`, I tried with `setPalette`,... I just find nothing working. Is there a way to set a specific `QMenuBar::item` property in C++ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found something.

1. Create your own object, for example `WidgetMenuBar`, inherited from `QMenuBar`.
2. Add a property to identify wich item should be colored differently:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < this->actions().size(); i++){
       actions().at(i)->setProperty("selection",false);
   }
   // Only the first item colored
   actions().at(0)->setProperty("selection",true);
   ```
3. Reimplement `void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)` function of your widget:

   ```
   void WidgetMenuBarMapEditor::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e){
       QPainter p(this);
       QRegion emptyArea(rect());

       // Draw the items
       for (int i = 0; i < actions().size(); ++i) {
           QAction *action = actions().at(i);
           QRect adjustedActionRect = this->actionGeometry(action);

           // Fill by the magic color the selected item
           if (action->property("selection") == true)
               p.fillRect(adjustedActionRect, QColor(255,0,0));

           // Draw all the other stuff (text, special background..)
           if (adjustedActionRect.isEmpty() || !action->isVisible())
               continue;
           if(!e->rect().intersects(adjustedActionRect))
               continue;
           emptyArea -= adjustedActionRect;
           QStyleOptionMenuItem opt;
           initStyleOption(&opt, action);
           opt.rect = adjustedActionRect;
           style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_MenuBarItem, &opt, &p, this);
       }
   }
   ```

You can see [here](https://github.com/openwebos/qt/blob/master/src/gui/widgets/qmenubar.cpp) how to implement paintEvent function.